# How to set username and password in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I don't understand how to set username and password to phpmyadmin. I have windows operating system and I'm using xampp.

Answer (score 0):

To set a username and password for phpMyAdmin on Windows, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your phpMyAdmin installation folder. This folder is typically located in the C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin directory if you are using XAMPP.
2. Locate the config.inc.php file in the installation folder and open it in a text editor.
3. In the config.inc.php file, find the line that says $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; and change the value of 'config' to 'cookie'. This will enable cookie-based authentication for phpMyAdmin.
4. Next, find the line that says $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; and replace 'root' with the username you want to use for phpMyAdmin.
5. Finally, find the line that says $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; and replace '' with the password you want to use for phpMyAdmin.

Save the config.inc.php file and restart your web server.

After completing these steps, you should be prompted to enter a username and password when you access phpMyAdmin. Enter the username and password you set in the config.inc.php file to log in to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'yusuf';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yusuf123!@sanal';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;



I edited the config.inc.php file as above, please correct me if I'm wrong.

but when i save and restart i got this error at login:

 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'yusuf'@'localhost' (using password: YES)